# Select rows based on count of child table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have three entities: department, employee, and report. A department has many employees, each of whom has many reports. I want to select the one employee in each department who has the most reports. I have no idea how to even start this query. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563148/one-to-many-query-selecting-all-parents-and-single-top-child-for-each-parent) seems very similar, but I can't figure out how to manipulate those answers for what I want.

I have full access to the entire system, so I can make any changes necessary. In the event of a tie, it's safe to arbitrarily pick one of the results.

Department:

```
 ID | Name
----|------
  1 | DeptA
  2 | DeptB
  3 | DeptC
  4 | DeptD
```

Employee:

```
 ID | Name | DeptID
----|------|--------
  1 | Joe  | 1
  2 | John | 1
  3 | Emma | 2
  4 | Jack | 3
  5 | Sven | 3
  6 | Axel | 4
  7 | Brad | 4
  8 | Jane | 4
```

Report:

```
 ID | EmployeeID
----|------------
  1 | 1
  2 | 2
  3 | 3
  4 | 5
  5 | 6
  6 | 6
  7 | 8
```

Desired result (assuming I queried names only):

```
Joe OR John (either is acceptable)
Emma
Sven
Axel
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to start this query?  Well, get the information about each employee, the department, and the number of reports:

```
select e.name, e.deptid, count(*) as numreports
from employee e join
     reports r
     on e.id = r.employeeid
group by e.name, e.deptid;
```

Now you just want the largest count in each department.  I would suggest `row_number()` or `rank()` depending on how you want to handle ties:

```
select er.*
from (select e.name, e.deptid, count(*) as numreports,
             row_number() over (partition by e.deptid order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from employee e join
           reports r
           on e.id = r.employeeid
      group by e.name, e.deptid
     ) er
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want the department name instead of number, you can join that in as well.

Comment: I would use a left-join, so that if no employees in a department have any reports, we still pick one of them.

Comment: I used a left join as suggested by @Blorgbeard, other than that this is spot on. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

From your Question schema will be

```
SELECT *  into  #Department FROM(
select 1 ID,'DEPTA' NAME
UNION ALL
select 2,'DEPTB'
UNION ALL
select 3,'DEPTC'
UNION ALL
select 4,'DEPTD')TAB

SELECT * INTO #Employee FROM (

SELECT  1 ID  ,'Joe' Name ,  1 DeptID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 , 'John'  , 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 , 'Emma'  ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 4  ,'Jack' , 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 5  ,'Sven' , 3
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 , 'Axel' , 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 7  ,'Brad' , 4
UNION ALL
SELECT 8  ,'Jane' , 4)AS A

SELECT * INTO  #Report FROM(
SELECT 1 ID  ,1 EmployeeID
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,  2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3  ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,  5
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,  6
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,  6
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,  8
UNION ALL
SELECT 8,  8
UNION ALL
SELECT 9,  8
)AS A
```

And you need to apply `DENSE_RANK()` for giving rank based on no of reports(count)

```
;WITH CTE AS(
select DEP.ID DEP_ID, DEP.NAME DEP,EMP.ID EMP_ID, EMP.Name EMP
,DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY DEP.ID ORDER BY  COUNT(REP.ID)  DESC) REP_RANK
,COUNT(REP.ID) NO_OF_REP FROM #Department DEP
inner join #Employee emp on emp.deptid=dep.id
inner join #report rep on rep.EmployeeID=emp.id
GROUP BY DEP.ID, DEP.NAME ,EMP.ID, EMP.Name 
)
SELECT DEP, EMP, NO_OF_REP FROM CTE WHERE REP_RANK=1
```

Here in the DEPTA Joe & John both will be picked because both are having 1 report count which is a max count in DEPTA.

And the result will be

```
+-------+------+-----------+
|  DEP  | EMP  | NO_OF_REP |
+-------+------+-----------+
| DEPTA | Joe  |         1 |
| DEPTA | John |         1 |
| DEPTB | Emma |         1 |
| DEPTC | Sven |         1 |
| DEPTD | Jane |         3 |
+-------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:-

```
SELECT D.NAME
FROM (
    SELECT C.NAME, RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY C.DEPTID ORDER BY C.COUNTS DESC
            ) RNK
    FROM (
        SELECT EMPID, NAME, COUNT(EMPID) AS COUNTS, DEPTID
        FROM DBO.REPORT AS A
        JOIN DBO.EMPLO AS B ON A.EMPID = B.ID
        GROUP BY EMPID, NAME, DEPTID
        ) AS C
    ) AS D
WHERE D.RNK = 1
```