# Microsoft Access: Query involving one parent and many children, select only the highest value child for each parent

Tags: ms-access

I have a parent table in a a one to many relationship to a child table. I would like to construct a query that returns all parent records, and for each parent record the corresponding child record that has the highest value in a particular field (a date).

In the Query Design, I have tried to use an Aggregate Function using 'Max'. As long as the only two fields in the query are the foreign key and the date, it works as I want. But when I add any other fields in the child table (eg the child's primary key) it reverts to listing each individual child entry.

I have tried following the solution in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563148/one-to-many-query-selecting-all-parents-and-single-top-child-for-each-parent): editing the answer to fit my database as follows:

```sql
SELECT tblRestrictivePractice.RestrictivePracticeID
    ,tblRestrictivePractice.Description
    ,tblStatusChange.StatusChangeID
    ,tblStatusChange.RestrictivePracticeID
    ,tblStatusChange.StartDate
FROM Parents tblRestrictivePractice
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT tblStatusChange1.StatusChangeID
        ,tblStatusChange1.RestrictivePracticeID
        ,tblStatusChange1.StartDate
    FROM Childs tblStatusChange1
    JOIN (
        SELECT tblRestrictivePractice1.RestrictivePracticeID
            ,max(tblStatusChange2.StartDate) maxStartDate
        FROM Parents tblRestrictivePractice1
        LEFT JOIN Childs tblStatusChange2 ON tblRestrictivePractice1.RestrictivePracticeID = tblStatusChange2.RestrictivePracticeID
        GROUP BY tblRestrictivePractice1.RestrictivePracticeID
        ) tblStatusChangef ON tblStatusChange1.RestrictivePracticeID = tblStatusChangef.StatusChangeID
        AND tblStatusChange1.StartDate = tblStatusChangef.maxStartDate
    ) StatusChange ON tblRestrictivePractice.RestrictivePracticeID = tblStatusChange.RestrictivePracticeID
```

However I get "Syntax Error in From Clause".

I am new, but have spent 8 hours banging my head against this, greatly appreciate any help.

Edit: Apologies, I should have clarified. The parent table is 'tblRestrictivePractice', the child table is 'tblStatusChange'. The Foreign key in the child table is 'RestrictivePracticeID' and the field I want to find the max entry of is 'StartDate'.

Comment: Check allowed JOIN statements for Ms Access, provide sample data, actual results and expected results [formated as table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (and in code fences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be simpler to use a subquery similar to:

```sql
SELECT 
    *,
    (SELECT TOP 1 StartDate
    FROM Child AS T
    WHERE T.RestrictivePracticeID = Parents.RestrictivePracticeID 
    ORDER BY T.StartDate DESC) AS LatestDate
FROM 
    Parents
```

Comment: So I gave this a shot. I set up a simple 'super' query just called 'Parents', and on line 4 replaced 'Child' with tblStatusChange (my child tablename), but it returned *all* the entries, not just the ones with the max StartDate. 
Can you tell where I went wrong?

Comment: Don't know. It will return each parent record once, each with an extra field having the latest date of the child records having  `RestrictivePracticeID ` as the foreign key of the child table and the primary key of the parents table.